# POST request from Salesforce Marketing Cloud cloudpage to Twilio using SSJS

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to send a POST request to Twilio's SMS API from Marketing Cloud's cloudpage using SSJS. I am getting a 401 unauthorized access even though I have added ACCOUNT_SID AND AUTH_TOKEN in the URL.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
      Platform.Load("core", "1");
  
  var config = {
        endpoint: "https://XXXX:XXXX@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXX/Messages.json",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       payload : "From=+0000&To=+0000&Body=Test1"
    }
  try {
        var httpResult = HTTP.Post(config.endpoint, config.contentType, config.payload);
            var result = JSON.parse(httpResult.response);
    Write(httpResult.StatusCode);
         Write('result' + result);
  } catch(error) { Write(Stringify(error)); }
  </script>
```

I get this error:
{"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

I have tried using client side JavaScript, but I get the same error.

```js
<script>

const url = 'https://XXXX:XXXX@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXX/Messages.json';
  
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  
 var data = 'From=+0000&To=+0000&Body=Test1';

xhr.send(data);
 
</script>
```

Comment: "*I have added ACCOUNT_SID AND AUTH_TOKEN in the URL.*" Can you cite a source upon which you're basing this implicit claim that passing your credentials like this meets the requirements for properly authorizing your request with the Twilio API, considering [its documentation clearly shows using `ACCOUNT_SID` and `AUTH_TOKEN` in a standard HTTP Basic Authorization header?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/requests-to-twilio#credentials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not familiar with SSJS and I'm finding it hard to connect [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPPost.html)(?) with what you've written. If [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationHTTPPost.html) refers to the same `HTTP.Post` method you are using then try something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">
  Platform.Load("core", "1");
  
  var accountSid = YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID;
  var authToken  = YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN;
  var auth = btoa(accountSid + ":" + authToken);

  var config = {
    endpoint: "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/XXXX/Messages.json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    payload : "From=+0000&To=+0000&Body=Test1"
  };

  try {
    var httpResult = HTTP.Post(
      config.endpoint,
      config.contentType,
      config.payload,
      ["Authorization"],
      ["Basic " + auth]
    );
      
    var result = JSON.parse(httpResult.response);
    Write(httpResult.StatusCode);
    Write('result' + result);
  } catch(error) {
    Write(Stringify(error));
  }
</script>
```

In this case I have concatenated the `accountSid` and `authToken` separated by a ":" then base 64 encoded the result. I then added an `Authorization` header to the HTTP request and set the value to `Basic`  plus the base64 encoded credentials.

Comment: I had to do some tweaks in the syntax but your solution was correct. Thanks a lot

Comment: Oh awesome! Glad it helped to get you there!